# geodesics in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let gamma be a straight line in a surface M. How can we prove that gamma is a geodesic?

ALl I note is that a geodesic on a surface M is a unit speed curve on M with geodesic curvature = 0 everywhere.

Update: To making it not look like the question is a tautology, check out this:

http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=407105

I'm trying to fill in the gaps and understand the argument for proving this theorem. Thanks

Comment: ..what do you mean by 'straight line'? Is $M$ embedded in $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: straight line = zero curvature

Comment: but that's the definition of geodesic, too, no?

Comment: Sorry, if gamma is a straight line, then we can say there exists a point xo that lies on every tangent line to gamma. Does this do the job?

Comment: @mary: no. Tangent lines don't lie in $M$, they lie in some tangent space. I don't see any way of answering this question that isn't tautologous. The correct definition of "straight line" _is_ geodesic.

Comment: There's an excellent pdf explaining geodesics on Riemannian manifolds here- http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/atariah/Files/WhatIs_AGeodesic.pdf They also have links to some nice animations to build intuition.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I think the OP is considering a surface (isometrically immersed) in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  By a "straight line in $M$," I think the OP means a geodesic in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that happens to lie in $M$.  The question is then why such a geodesic in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is then a geodesic in $M$.

Comment: @Berci: Yes and no.  The definition of a geodesic _in_ $\mathbb{R}^3$ is that $\kappa = 0$ (what the OP refers to as "zero curvature").  The definition of a geodesic _in_ $M$ is $\kappa_g = 0$ ("zero geodesic curvature").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the formula
$$\kappa^2 = \kappa_g^2 + \kappa_n^2.$$

Here, $\kappa_g$ is the geodesic curvature, $\kappa_n$ is the normal curvature, and $\kappa$ is (unfortunately) just called the "curvature" (it is the $\kappa$ that appears in the Frenet-Serret Formulas).

A straight line has $\kappa = 0$, so....

Comment: so then if kappa = 0 and kappag = 0, then the result is that kappan = 0 so everything is zero. But how can you incorporate this argument in an iff statement

Comment: My point is that if $\kappa = 0$, then $\kappa_g = 0$.  This says exactly that straight lines are geodesics.

Comment: The converse is false: geodesics in $M$ are not necessarily straight lines.

Comment: how do we know that kappag = 0?

Comment: Why is it if kappa=0 then Kappasubg =0?

Comment: I'll let you think about that one on your own.